# Oracle Apex Change link column color

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have Interactive report in apex application where first  column `USER_GID` includes links or is a  link column.

How do i change the color of the link?

[image]

Here column `USER_ID` contains links.

So 23, is a link and i want to change its color to blue.

So the links are distinguished.

How can i do that?

Apex 20.2

Answer (score 2):

As I don't have your table, I used Scott's `EMP`. The idea is: if `DEPTNO` column represents a link (I used the one to Google), paint it differently for each department number.

Interactive report's query would then look like

```
select 
  '<a href="https://www.google.com" style="color:' ||
    case when deptno = 10 then 'red'
         when deptno = 20 then 'green'
         else 'pink'
    end  ||
    '">' || deptno || '</a>' detpno,
  --
  empno, ename, job
from emp
order by ename
```

Don't forget to set `deptno` column's "Escape special characters" property to "No".

The result is then

[image]

Comment: All columns need to have only one color, blue. So i wouldn't need a case right?

Comment: I just showed how to use different colors, if you want. If you don't need that, then you don't need CASE either.

Comment: select 
  '<a href="https://www.google.com" style="color:blue' ||

    '">' || deptno || '</a>' detpno,
  --
  empno, ename, job
from emp
order by ename

Comment: Test it yourself and see the result.

Comment: This doesn't work, it is simple printing the html tag in column value

Comment: It wouldn't harm if you actually read what I wrote. Let's repeat: **Don't forget to set deptno column's "Escape special characters" property to "No".**

Comment: A better method is to collate this information in the HTML expression, such as <span style="color:#MY_COLOR_COLUMN#">#ENAME#</span>